# Ubuntu VM with no IPv4 connection, only IPv6

Tags: 16.04, ipv6

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM installed on my cloud provider. I cannot get IPv4 connectivity but only IPv6. I can connect to my VM through secure shell and I can also reach it through its domain name (I have installed an Apache HTTP server and I can see the test page). However, I wonder why I don't have normal access to the internet. For example, when I run `sudo apt-get update` some package repositories seem to be reachable while others don't. I have also tried to ping various web sites with no success.

What is going on? What should I do to allow my VM to have normal network access?

```
ifconfig 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:02:ed:99:a2  
              inet6 addr: fe80::a800:2ff:feed:99a2/64 Scope:Link
              inet6 addr: 2001:648:2ffc:1225:a800:2ff:feed:99a2/64 Scope:Global
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:5690 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:3475 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:2910088 (2.9 MB)  TX bytes:534675 (534.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:24067 (24.0 KB)  TX bytes:24067 (24.0 KB)
```

Comment: Does your provider actually provide IPv4 addresses at all? What's in your system logs?

Comment: My cloud provider gives 3 IPv4 addresses for 20 VMs. For this VM, I cannot use an IPv4 address as I need them for other VMs. Which log do you refer to exactly?

Comment: I would first check `/var/log/syslog`. That's where common system activity gets logged. But if your VM hasn't got IPv4 connectivity at all, then there is no point. You can only access IPv6 sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few different transition technologies which will allow an IPv6-only client to reach an IPv4-only service. I would expect most IPv6-only hosting providers to offer one of those transition solutions in their default configuration. And I believe DNS64+NAT64 is the transition solution most often chosen for this.

You should ask your provider if they have a DNS64+NAT64 setup for you to use.

Should the provider not have any NAT64 there is a few public NAT64 that you can make use of. I know of two providers which are currently operational:

- http://www.trex.fi/2011/dns64.html
- https://go6lab.si/current-ipv6-tests/nat64dns64-public-test/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do. This seems like an answer to my problem.